# Formatting EAN8 with zxing/barcode4j

Tags: java, format, barcode, zxing, barcode4j

I am trying to generate an EAN8-barcode in java. If tried barcode4j (which is free in contrary to the barcodelib), which gives me really good results.

One thing I haven't figured out is to change the width and the height of the barcode in barocde4j. I have solved it by the resolution parameter, which isn't imho that good solution.

What i wanna do is generating everthing in zxing (because i also need  QR code), but the result look quite ugly. This is how i generate the barcode:

```
BitMatrix matrix;
com.google.zxing.Writer writer = new EAN8Writer();
com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat BarcodeFormat;
matrix = writer.encode(code,BarcodeFormat, width, height);
MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(matrix, "JPG", output);
```

Picture looks with zxing like

[image: zxing]

But i wish it would look like barcode4j does it:

[image: barcode4j]

regards && tia
  noircc

Comment: Did you mean to embed some images with this question? They didn't embed.

Comment: yeah i tried to embed it from imgur. i made the exclamation mark and the square-brackets. maybe it won't work with this site.

Comment: ah ok you can upload pictures to stackoverflow. got it now :)

Comment: You can't add digits in zxing, but you can add them by editing the BufferedImage you get back. That's not so hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Barcode4J: you can only indirectly control the size of the barcode. If you generate barcodes with the bean method, you have setHeight(double) and setModuleWidth(double) to influence the size:

[EAN8Bean javadoc](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/trunk/javadocs/org/krysalis/barcode4j/impl/upcean/EAN8Bean.html)

With XML configuration, you can find the possible values [here](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/symbol-ean-8.html).

And BTW, I strongly recommend NOT to generate JPEGs for barcode because it's a lossy format which can have an influence on contrast and barcodes live off contrast. Use PNG instead! Furthermore, you might want to read the [troubleshooting page](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/troubleshooting.html) since you're generating bitmaps. It can help avoid scanning problems later.